# NS2 environment variables settings in .bashrc file in Cygwin

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin, environment-variables, ns2

I have installed NS2 on Cygwin. I can't run it because it seems I have set environmental variables wrongly.
Here is my .bashrc file.

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions

OTCL_LIB=ns-allinone/otcl-1.9
NS2_LIB=ns-allinone/lib
USR_LOCAL_LIB=/usr/local/lib
X11_LIB=/usr/X11R6/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$OTCL_LIB:$NS2_LIB:$USR_LOCAL_LIB

TCL_LIB=ns-allinone/tcl8.5.10/library
USR_LIB=/usr/lib
export TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIB:$USR_LIB

XGRAPH=/ns-allinone/bin:/ns-allinone/tcl8.5.10/unix:/ns-allinone/tk8.5.10/unix
NS=ns-allinone/ns-2.28/
NAM=ns-allinone/nam-1.11/
TCL=ns-allinone/tcl8.4.5/unix
TK=ns-allinone/tk8.4.5/unix
```

Comment: You probably need to `export XGRAPH NS NAM TCL TK` at the end.  If you don't do that then those are local variables, not environment variables.

Comment: @cdarke I added the line you mentioned but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you source the .bashrc file before you tried it?

Comment: @cdarke You mean by this  source ~/.bashrc  ? I just ran this command on Cygwin.

Comment: "Sourcing" is using the "dot" command.  This will run the script in the current process, if you run ~/.bashrc as a command then it will run in a child process and have no effect on the parent.  So use: `. ~/.bashrc`.  Logging-off then logging-on again should have the same effect.

Comment: @cdarke Still not working. I think the problem is with my bashrc file.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has not the same effect on cygwin than on a Unix. Try to replicate it with `PATH`. also change `X11_LIB=/usr/lib` or `/usr/bin` as `/usr/X11R6/lib` does not exist anymore.

Comment: @matzeri Still not working...

Comment: not working is vague. You should provide more info and error messages

Comment: @matzeri ns: command not found.

Comment: and do you have a file called `ns` or `ns.exe` on your installation ?

Comment: @matzeri Yes it seems ns has been installed successfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118735/discussion-between-matzeri-and-hanna).

Comment: @matzeri I ran ns.exe and it seems cygwin1.dll is missing!

Comment: unlikely. No cywin program will be able to run without it, including bash.

Comment: @matzeri I copied cygwin1.dll in the folder that ns.exe exists. Now there is no error about Cygwin. But `ns: command not found` has not been changed.